# Implementing drag and drop zone in meteor.js

Tags: meteor, drag-and-drop

I just tried the below **code**

```
Template.gallery.events({
  'dropped #dropzone': function(event, temp) {
    console.log('files dropped');
    Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
      stores: [new
        FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {
          path: "~/meteor_uploads"
        })
      ]
    });
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      console.log("each file ...")
      var images = new FS.File(file);
      Images.insert(images, function(err, fileObj) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("inserted without error");
        } else {
          console.log("there was an error", err);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

And if anything dropped into drop zone got this **error**

*files dropped 

each file ... 

files dropped 

Storage name already exists:"images"
there was an error 
 
errorClass{error:404,reason:Method not found:,details:undefined,message:"Method not found[404]",errorType: "Meteor.Error"}*

**Give some suggestions to resolve it**

Answer (score 0):

Move the following code out of the event handler, to somewhere that it will execute on the client (or both on the client and server) before the event will be triggered.

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", { stores: [
         new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", { path: "~/meteor_uploads" })
       ]});
```

This line is throwing the error you showed the second time it is executed.  In that traceback this second execution is triggered while the first execution is waiting for the `Images.insert` callback

Comment: Problem got **resolved** . It works when code is moved outside the client block

Comment: If you want to call `Images.insert` on the client in an event handler, you have to first define `Images` on the client.